# relationship between sample size requirement and resulting p value

Tags: p-value, sample-size

If one uses a web-based sample size calculator for a chi square analysis, the resulting sample size seems to have little relationship to the sample size required to obtain significance, eg. .05. For example, using proportions of .4 and .5, (correcting for continuity, alpha=.05, beta=.2), the required sample size per group is 407. But if you use these proportions with sample size of 407, the resulting p value is .004. Why the discrepancy? thanks.

Comment: There isn't really enough information here for this to be answered. The result is significant. Are you disappointed the p-value isn't exactly.05? Did you conduct a power analysis, get an N, run a study and get a conflicting result?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer this in general, but use illustrations that are based on the specific example you gave.

When we specify the alternative hypothesis for a power calculation, this is an assumption about the *true* (fixed) underlying parameter values. The result of a significance test depends on the *observed* (random) parameter estimates.

For a particular significance test, we can calculate a critical value of the test statistic that will give a significant result for some chosen type I error level. This calculation is based on the (often approximate) distribution of the test statistic under the null hypothesis. If the *observed* test statistic is larger than this critical value, we have a statistically significant result and can reject the null hypothesis.

**Example:** For a Chi-squared test on a 2x2 table, the distribution of the test statistic under the null hypothesis is Chi-squared with 1 degree of freedom. That looks like this:
[image: Density and distribution of Chi-squared(1) rv]
Marked in red is the critical value for a Chi-squared test with a significance level of 0.05: we expect the observed test statistic to exceed this value 5% of the time, just by chance, when the null hypothesis is true. This value is 3.84 (you might recognise it as $1.96^2$)

The key here is that the observed parameter estimates are random variables, as is the resulting test statistic that is used in the significance test. The distribution of this test statistic depends on the true underlying parameter values, and the sample size.

**Example:** Below are some kernel density estimates of the observed difference in proportions, and resulting test statistic from simulated examples with a sample size of 400 in each group and different underlying true proportions. You can see that the observed difference hovers around the true difference, but it can be much smaller or larger. The test statistic is expected to be larger when the true difference between the proportions increases.
[image: Distribution of observed difference from simulations with differing p]
[image: Distribution of observed test statistic from simulations with differing p]

If the alternative hypothesis is true, it's pretty unlikely that the observed parameter values will be exactly the same as their true values. We may, simply by chance, actually observe more events in the group with the lower risk. But this becomes less likely if we use a larger sample.

**Example:** Here are the same plots as above, this time keeping the true proportions as p1 = 0.4 and p2 = 0.6, but changing the sample size.
[image: Distribution of observed difference from simulations with differing n]
[image: Distribution of observed test statistic from simulations with differing n]
Again the observed difference hovers around the true difference (0.2), but the variation in this gets smaller as the sample size gets larger. The test statistic is expected to be larger when the sample size is larger, because we have less chance of observing small differences in the proportions.

When we perform a sample size calculation, we consider the distribution of the test statistic as a function of the (assumed) true parameter values according to the alternative hypothesis and the sample size. Based on this distribution, we can calculate the proportion of the time that we expect the observed test statistic to be above the critical value, producing a significant result. The sample size is selected to be the one that gives us a certain probability that our observed test statistic is greater than the critical value. This probability is the power.

**Example:** The graph below shows the density of the observed difference and the test statistic under the alternative hypothesis (p1 = 0.4, p2 = 0.5) with a sample size of n = 407 per group, as in your scenario. You can see that although the true difference in proportions is 0.1, the observed difference may be smaller than this, and there is a possibility that it will be so small that we do not see a statistically significant result.
[image: Density of difference and test statistic in the given scenario]

The red line is at the critical value of 3.84. The area under the density curve to the right of the line is the probability that our test statistic exceeds the critical value, that is, the probability that our result is statistically significant (p < 0.05). This value is 80%, which is the power that you used in your sample size calculation.

Finally, you said in your question that the "resulting sample size seems to have little relationship to the sample size required to obtain significance". In fact, had you performed your power calculation with 50% power, you would have (approximately) found the sample size required to obtain statistical significance *if the observed difference is the same as the difference under the alternative hypothesis*. The left-hand graph above shows that the observed difference is approximately symmetric: it will be smaller than the true difference about 50% of the time. So, if the *true* difference in proportions is the same as the difference that produces a test statistic equal to the critical value (i.e. large enough to obtain a significant result), our *observed* difference has only 50% chance of being this large.

Try performing a power calculation with a type I error rate of 0.004, a type II error rate of 0.5 (power = 50%), p1 = 0.4 and p2 = 0.5. You should get n = 407 per group again.

Comment: Yes, the calculated n under these conditions is 406. thanks for your very thoughtful response. bill